# How can I take the last digits of this string

Tags: php

How can I take the last digits of this string in PHP?

I want to create a student id for this I use the if else statement if the student table is empty then the first value will be for22dl1
after that you it will increase like for22dl2 in the next row.

Examples:
string = for22dl1
output = 1

String = for22dl120
output = 120

```
// Generate Student ID
$year=date('y');
$sql = "select sno from students ORDER BY sno DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$id=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) >0){
  //found
  $id = $id['student_id'];
  // here i want to write code for get the last digits after dl
  $sid = $id + 1;
  $string="for$year dl$sid";
  $student_id = preg_replace('/\\s+/', '', $string);

}else{
  //not found
  $string="for$year dl1";
  $student_id = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
}
```

Comment: This is a bad idea and can easily lead to duplicate values when there's contention. Don't generate your own IDs. Let the database generate unique IDs reliably for you using an auto increment column

Answer (score 2):

Thanks
Now its working for me:

```
    $regex = '/dl(\d+)/';
    preg_match($regex, $id, $matches); 
    $matches=array_shift($matches);
    // output was dl220 (string + digit) Now filter the digit only 
    
    $int = (int) filter_var($matches, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $sid = $int + 1;
    $string="for$year dl$sid";
    $student_id = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 1):

**$matches is resulted array,
matches [0] is a string starting from dl to onward and matches[1] is your last integer value**

```
  // Use preg_match() to extract the last digits from the string
  $regex = '/dl(\d+)/';
  preg_match($regex, $id, $matches);
```